# Undefined jQuery passando via button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando passando o `cod_historico` via jQuery, dentro de um botão, que vou abrir uma modal, para buscar visualizações internas de um conteúdo específico.

Estou gerando uma lista vinda com registros do banco de dados:

```
<tbody>
    <? 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($interessados as $valor){ 
    ?>
    <tr role="row">
        <td><? echo $valor->int_nome; ?></td>
        <? if($this->session->userdata['con_cod_tipo']=='2'){ ?>
        <td><? echo $valor->int_cod_unidade; ?></td>
        <? } ?>
        <td><? echo $valor->int_cod_consultora; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $valor->int_cod_curso; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $valor->int_cod_campanha; ?></td>
        <td><? echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($valor->int_data)); ?></td>
        <td><? echo $valor->int_status; ?></td>
        <td style="width: 12%">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-custom" name="visualizar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#visualiza-historico" data-cod_historico="<? echo $valor->int_cod; ?>"><i class="fa fa-history"></i></button>
                </a>
                <a href="<? echo base_url("index.php/interessado/editar/".$valor->int_cod); ?>">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-custom"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                </a>
                <? if($this->session->userdata['con_cod_tipo']=='2'){ ?>
                <a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-custom" name="deletar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirma-deletar" data-href="<? echo base_url("index.php/interessado/deletar/".$valor->int_cod); ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </a>
                <? } ?>
            </div>                    
        </td>
    </tr>
    <? $i++; } ?>
</tbody>
```

E estou usando este jQuery para buscar o cod_historico do botão, com o alert:

```
$('#visualiza-historico').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $("#cod_historico").val($(this).data('cod_historico'));
    alert(cod_historico);

    var url = "<? echo base_url("index.php/interessado/historico/"); ?>/" + $("#cod_historico").val() ;
    $('#div_historico_prospects').html("<div><center><img src='<? echo base_url("themes/default/dist/img") ?>/loading_anim.gif'><br><br><strong>Por favor, aguarde que estamos buscando o histórico...</strong></center></div>");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#div_historico_prospects').load(url);
    },5000);
});
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: A primeira linha do seu jQuery parece estar repetida. É isso mesmo?

Comment: na sua terceira linha voce esta procurando `#cod_historico`, isto é um `id`.
onde esta o `id` do seu botão? e outra nao se deve repetir ids
coloque uma classe por ex `meu_btn` e ao invez de chamar `$("#cod_historico")`.
vc chama `$(".meu_btn")`.

Comment: Está no data-cod_historico, o id